# Jquery .slideToggle() not working on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my `html.css` this is how I call the `.js` file
`<script src="slideul.js"></script>` it is after the ending tag of body. 
I followed the steps but I don't know what is the problem.
I need to hide first the ul and then pop the ul whenever the user clicks the button.

```js
$('.btnrefine').next('.list-unstyled').hide();
$('.btnrefine').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.list-unstyled').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="category">
  <div class="title-bg">
    <h3 class="category-title"><button type="button" class="btnrefine"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><span>Categories</span></h3>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="" title="">Men's Apparel</li>
 <li><a href="" title="">Mobile and Gadgets</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Consumer Electronics</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Miscellaneous</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Men's Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Men's Shoes</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Hobbies and Stationery</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Toys, Kids and Babies</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Bags</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Women's Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Women's Shoes</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Sports and Outdoors</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not at all clear what you're asking. "Not working well" is not a useful problem description. What happens? What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: *"it is after the ending tag of body"* That's not a valid location for it. Just **before** the closing `</body>` tag is the best place for your `script` tags barring a specific reason to do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to `slidetoggle` the menu with the `menubutton` click see below for that, why are you trying to use `.next()` do you have multiple menu lists? if not you need to do it a simple way, otherwise you still need to use `.parent().parent().next('.list-unstyled')`and you should add the script inside the head or before the `</body>` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.list-unstyled').hide();
  $('.btnrefine').click(function() {
    //console.log($(this).parent().parent().next());
    $(this).parent().parent().next('.list-unstyled').slideToggle();
  });

  //if not multiple menus
  //  $('.list-unstyled').hide();
  // $('.btnrefine').click(function() {
  //  $('.list-unstyled').slideToggle();
  // });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="category">
  <div class="title-bg">
    <h3 class="category-title">
      <button type="button" class="btnrefine">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <span>Categories</span>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="" title="">Men's Apparel</li>
       <li><a href="" title="">Mobile and Gadgets</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Consumer Electronics</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Miscellaneous</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Men's Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Men's Shoes</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Hobbies and Stationery</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Toys, Kids and Babies</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Bags</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Women's Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Women's Shoes</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Sports and Outdoors</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you're codeis working but when i apply it to mine it doesn't. hmm is it correct if i put your document ready function to  a separate .js file?? and call it in html file like this: <script src="slideul.js"></script>

Comment: yes that would be fine if you even put it in a separate file but you need to include that script after `jquery.min.js`